# Styling not refreshing for old visitors on WordPress

Tags: css, cache, sass

I’m working on correcting a styling of an element on an WP-based eCommerce site.

The site has both SCSS and CSS files.

To make things quick, I edited the CSS via Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS.

However, when I was done and published my changes (and solved the issue), only those new to the website sees the difference.

Those who have visited the site prior to the deployment of the solution, still see the distorted number layout

I also suspected that the SCSS gets compiled every refresh but when I checked the File Manager (cPanel), only the CSS files get modified.

I’m feeling this might be a cache-related issue. I have already disabled a cache plugin (WP Rocket). However, the problem still persists.

I did try to use Incognito and the change did reflect. However, the users of the site are non-techy people and don't know how to refresh.

The site is using GoDaddy as the host. Is it possible the issue is on that part?

What possible issue am I experiencing?

Thank you

Comment: Check with your host to see if they use a server-side cache such as Varnish.  If so, note that Varnish is a pretty aggressive cache, so you'd probably have to manually clear it.  If there is additional server-side cache, your host can help you navigate how to flush it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the issue you are experiencing is related to caching. When a website is visited, the browser stores certain assets (such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files) in a cache to improve the performance of the website. This means that when a user revisits the website, their browser will load the stored assets from the cache rather than fetching them from the server again.

This can cause issues when you make changes to the website, as the user's browser may still be using the old, cached assets. To solve this problem, you can try to clear the cache for your website.

There are several ways you can do this:

Use the "Hard Refresh" option in your browser: You can try using the "Hard Refresh" option in your browser to clear the cache for your website. This option is usually available by pressing the Ctrl + F5 keys on a PC, or the Command + Shift + R keys on a Mac.

Clear the cache in your browser's settings: You can also try clearing the cache in your browser's settings. The steps to do this will vary depending on the browser you are using.

Use a cache plugin: If you are using a cache plugin on your WordPress site (such as WP Rocket), you can try clearing the cache through the plugin's settings.

Clear the server cache: If you are using a hosting provider that has caching enabled (such as GoDaddy), you can try clearing the server cache through your hosting account's control panel.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions or need additional assistance.